# free variable in parametric form

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, parametric

if I have say $x_4$ = free, what value goes in the $x_4$ position of the parametric form, is it $1$ or $0$ or can it be any value since it's free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Free" is not a value and "x4=free" is an abuse of the equal sign.  You mean $x_4$ *is* free.  *Is* can denote equality ($=$), but here it denotes membership ($\in$).  I had originally put this as a postscript, but your comments on my first drafts indicate this might be a stumbling block for you.

If $x_4$ is a free variable, it should be left as a parameter since it can have, as you say, any value.

You can express the other variables in terms of the free variables, or you can give names like $s$ and $t$ to the parameters and express all $x_i$ variables in terms of $s$ and $t$.

It sounds like your specific general solution is:
\begin{align*}
    x_4 &\text{is free} \\
    x_3 &= x_4 \\
    x_2 &= 0 \\
    x_1 &= 3x_4
\end{align*}
"$x_4$ is free" means that you can't say anything more specific than $x_4 = x_4$.  So (in vector form) $[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4] = [3x_4,0,x_4,x_4] = x_4[3,0,1,1]$.  Alternatively, you could say $[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4] = [3x_4,0,x_4,x_4] = t[3,0,1,1]$, where $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I have x4[3,0,1,#], I expressed the first 3 values in terms of x4, but not sure what to put in # since it's the x4 term which is free

Comment: @user3427042: You mean the general solution is $[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4] = [3x_4,0,x_4,x_4]$?  If so, then #=1.

Comment: gen sol: 3x4,0,x4,free. so as you said, it's 1 correct?

Answer (score 0):

You just say $x_4 = t$, $t\in \Bbb R$

Example:
$$\mathbf v = [x_1, x_2, x_3, 0] + t[0, 0, 0, 1],\quad t\in \Bbb R$$
$x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are set values while $t$ is free.

Comment: I have x4[3,0,1,#], I expressed the first 3 values in terms of x4, but not sure what to put in # since it's the x4 term which is free

Comment: If you want your vector to be [3*x4, 0*x4, 1*x4, x4] you must set # to one.